# how to generate RTF content from an xml file and xslt having html tags

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xsd

I have xml file and xslt formatted using html, is there any tool or renderer which would accept these two as input and output an rtf equivalent using C#

Comment: Can You give some examples of your html and rtf You expect to get from that html?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what is your input - HTML or some kind of XML?

If you need to convert HTML to RTF my suggestion would be to use Word - it can be controlled from C# easily and it can open HTML and save RTF. This will work fine on a client, it becomes tricky on a server though.

If your input is some simple/standard HTML (e.g. using only a restricted set of tags in a regular way and without CSS) you can convert it to some simple RTF directly with a XSLT